# Create Date and Time Format from current time

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I have to pass this format to hit third api

Format: "2015-09-30T14:15:11Z";

How can i achieve this using php.

Suppose current date time is 2018-07-18 12:23:10 and i want it to be like this "2018-07-18T12:23:10Z"

Comment: replace space character " " with "T" with str_replace() and then append the "Z" character with a + sign.

Comment: Suggest you use the DateTime class (or `date()`) to create the format you need. String replacing is, imo, a bad approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try with below

```
 echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", strtotime("2018-07-18 12:23:10")) //2018-07-18T12:23:10Z
```

For current time you can use...

```
 echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))) //2018-07-19T07:03:04Z
```